# How to return a list value with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: example of the CSV I want to create]

I need to create a CSV with data exported from an Oracle DB. There are three tables I want to pull data from Students, Contacts, Staff. One of the columns in my resulting CSV needs to be a comma-separated list of related IDs. This is the "agentSourcedIds" column in my example above. How do I return a list of all related record ids with SQL?

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data *and* desired results, as tabular text (2) What have you tried so far, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are you wondering how to write the query because your column includes commas? If you are using a tool like Razor, then you don't need to worry about it. Using the export wizard, there's an option to wrap the values in quotes when the value includes a delimiter.

Comment: And if tool does not allow that, then just concatenate the column with quotes, like this: select column1, column2, '"' || column3 || '"'

Comment: Have a look at the [`listagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) function.